# MS Access - change date format of local database only

Tags: datetime, ms-access

I'm based in the UK and I'm developing an MS Access 2016 database for an American client.

How can I change the language settings ***for this database only*** and not Access in general so, for example in table design view field format options for date appear appear as mm/dd/yyyy, mm/dd/yy etc rather than dd/mm/yyyy, dd/mm/yy?

I know I can format the data post-hoc using SQL or VBA but I'd prefer to set the behaviour as default at the design stage to limit the potential for error.

Many thanks.

Update, here's the options currently presented for the field format:

[image]

Comment: Yes, use _Short Date_ for a display using the Windows settings - which in the US will be _m/d/yyyy_.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Format property of table fields and textboxes to: mm/dd/yyyy

But that will not change the behaviour of, say, DateValue which still will read a date string like "6/7/2016" as 2016-07-06 using your Windows settings.

So the real answer is that you can not. And neither should you need it - if you don't apply custom formats, your database will display dates as m/d/yyyy when reaching your American client.

If you want to see your application in action, install a virtual machine with US settings, and test your application in this environment.